# Tabindex -1 not working with iOS

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I have the following code, the problem is when the user is pressing the "Go" Button on the iOS keyboard, the button with the function `scanBarcode()` gets invoked. But normally, when the user press the "Go"-Button on the keyboard, the form should be submit (`submitForm()`) . I can't change the order of the buttons, because the button with the `scanBarcode()` function is directly beside the input. I tried to skip this Scanbutton with tabindex -1 but this seems not to work.

```
<form #submitForm="ngForm">

    <ion-item>
                  <ion-label stacked>Masternumber:</ion-label>
                  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="masternum" name="masternumber" (ngModelChange)="inputFgnr()" #masternumber="ngModel" required autofocus></ion-input>

                    <button style="width: 30px; padding: 0 !important" ion-button large icon-only ion-button clear item-right tabindex="-1" (click)="scanBarcode()">
                              <ion-icon name="ios-camera"></ion-icon>
                   </button>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button block icon-right type="submit" (click)="submitForm()">

    </form>
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=tabindex // I don’t see what tabindex even has to do with _pressing_ buttons? It comes into play when you tab-navigate through elements. But how would it influence what happens _when_ a button is pressed (according to your problem description, that is when things start going wrong) …?

Comment: Alright, maybe I have chosen the wrong title. But I actually dont know how to call it, maybe you can help me. I guess my problem is clear in the description.